# Automation of desktop using winium Java

Tags: java, selenium, winium

how to close tab automatically if there are more than 5 tabs open.
I can open different tabs using selenium now I have to check if there is more than 5 tab then it should close by its own.
I tried to go to the task manager using winium but I don't understand what I have to do next.

Comment: I want to check Task Manager automatically for more chrome tabs and close the ones open 5 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are initiating to open a URL, add below code

```
Set<String> WHandles= driver.getWindowHandles();
int WHandleCnt= WHandles.size();
if(WHandleCnt>5){
  for(int i=0;i<WHandleCnt;i++){
    String CurrentTab= WHandles.iterator().next();
    driver.switchTo().window(CurrentTab);
    driver.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to check Task Manager automatically for more chrome tabs and close the ones open 5 hours ago. Can you help me with this?